# Удалить отмеченные чекбоксы. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Как решить задачу? Нужно найти все отмеченные чекбоксы и удалить их с родителем. Конструкция такая:

*javascript*

```
function remove(appendBox) { }
```

*HTML*

```
<a class="btn" onclick="remove('box22')" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a>

<div id="box22">
    <div class="unit" data-id="11">
        <input type="checkbox" id="unitObject11" name="unitObject[]" value="11">
        <label for="unitObject11">11</label>
    </div>
    <div class="unit" data-id="56">
        <input type="checkbox" id="unitObject56" name="unitObject[]" value="56">
        <label for="unitObject56">56</label>
    </div>
    <!-- etc... -->
</div>
```

Спасибо!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function remove(appendBox) { 
  var items = document.getElementById(appendBox).querySelectorAll(".unit input[type='checkbox']:checked");
  items.forEach(item => item.closest('.unit').remove());
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" onclick="remove('box22')" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a>

<div id="box22">
    <div class="unit" data-id="11">
        <input type="checkbox" id="unitObject11" name="unitObject[]" value="11">
        <label for="unitObject11">11</label>
    </div>
    <div class="unit" data-id="56">
        <input type="checkbox" id="unitObject56" name="unitObject[]" value="56">
        <label for="unitObject56">56</label>
    </div>
    <!-- etc... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо очень четко и коротко!

Answer (score 1):

для того, чтобы выбрать все чекбоксы, нужен селектор

```
input[type="checkbox"]
```

Чтобы выбрать только выделенные, нужно добавить селектор `:checked`

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked
```

Для выбора можно воспользоваться методом [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

для обращения как каждому конкретному элементу в выборке, можно использовать цикл [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Для получения родительского элемента служит свойство [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

Чтобы удалить полученный элемент можно использовать метод [`.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения.